# VS2010: ListView returns no data, even when the tested query while configuring the data source works fine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, listview, stored-procedures, sqldatasource

I'm trying to populate a ListView with this stored procedure:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.PlayersWithFilter
    (
    @filter varchar(255) = NULL,
    @team int = NULL
    )
AS
    IF @filter IS NULL
        BEGIN
            SELECT        P1.PlayerKey, P1.Player, P2.Position, T1.TeamAbbreviation, P1.Height, P1.Weight, P1.Speed, P1.Status
            FROM          Player AS P1
            INNER JOIN    Position AS P2 ON P1.PositionID = P2.PositionID
            INNER JOIN    Team AS T1 ON T1.TeamID = P1.TeamID
            WHERE         P1.TeamID = @team
            ORDER BY      P2.PosSort;
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT        P1.PlayerKey, P1.Player, P2.Position, T1.TeamAbbreviation, P1.Height, P1.Weight, P1.Speed, P1.Status
            FROM          Player AS P1
            INNER JOIN    Position AS P2 ON P1.PositionID = P2.PositionID
            INNER JOIN    Team AS T1 ON T1.TeamID = P1.TeamID
            WHERE         P1.Player LIKE '%' + @filter + '%'
            ORDER BY      P2.PosSort;
        END
```

Now if I test this in the "Test Query" section of the "configuring data source" it works.  When I try to work with it in the browser while debugging it always returns no rows though. If I comment out the IF statement and @filter parameter and just work with the @team parameter then it works. Anyone can spot the problem or suggest something to try? Thanks.

Comment: Are you passing different values for the params when you are debugging?

Comment: I've tried all sorts of different values. I even left one empty and filled another in trying to get even a default situation to show (ie. team=2, filter=[nothing sent]). Like I said it works on the test query but not once I go to debug. not sure why that is. I'm new to Stored Procedures so I was guessing perhaps I had done something incorrectly.

Comment: What can you see being passed into this stored proc and subsequent select statement in Sql Server Profiler?

Comment: I'm using sql server 2008 express... i dont think it has sql profiler. any other stofware i can use to see same stuff?

Comment: I have not used it, but this might help [sqlexpressprofiler](http://code.google.com/p/sqlexpressprofiler/)

Comment: Shows same results as I'd expect. Seems to be a ASP.NET list view problem... perhaps something I dont have setup correctly but I'm not sure what it could be.  The listview works if I have a 1 parameter, no conditional statement Stored Procedure. As soon as I do something like above though it doesn't seem to want to work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently there is a property for the SQLDataSource called, "CancelSelectOnNullParameter" ... yeah.